# No junit results (pass OR fail) displayed in terminal

Tags: java, junit, command-line, terminal

I'm running the demo in:

https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Getting-started

I copied Calculator and CalculatorTest exactly as displayed in the page.  Compiling failed though:

```
D:\workspace\junit-example>java -cp d:\junit\latest\junit.jar;. CalculatorTest
Error: Main method not found in class CalculatorTest, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
```

So I created this file:

```
public class Runner {

    public Runner() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CalculatorTest c = new CalculatorTest();
        c.evaluatesExpression();
    }

}
```

The problem is, even though everything compiles and runs (see output below), there isn't any output from JUnit.  What is needed to see the result of the test?

```
D:\workspace\junit-example>javac -cp d:\junit\latest\junit.jar;. *.java

D:\workspace\junit-example>java -cp d:\junit\latest\junit.jar;. Runner

D:\workspace\junit-example>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need your `Runner` class. Instead, when you run your program, specify `org.junit.runner.JUnitCore` as the class to run, not `CalculatorTest`. That way, JUnit will run the test. It's mentioned further down on the page you linked to, under "Run the test."

`java -cp .;junit-4.XX.jar;hamcrest-core-1.3.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CalculatorTest`

Comment: That fails.  D:\workspace\junit-example>java -cp d:\junit\latest\junit.jar;D:\hamcrest\latest\hamcrest-core.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore CalculatorTest
JUnit version 4.12
.E
Time: 0.016
There was 1 failure:
1) initializationError(org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find class [CalculatorTest]
        at org.junit.runner.JUnitCommandLineParseResult.parseParameters(JUnitCommandLineParseResult.java:102)
FAILURES!!!
Tests run: 1,  Failures: 1h of runtime errors.

Comment: You need to include CalculatorTest in your classpath. You forgot the `.;` as shown in the example.

Answer (score 2):

You are running it in a wrong way.
You do not need `Runner` class at all. Also you need to run **jUnit runner class** and pass class with test methods as a parameter. This is mentioned in that tutorial:

> java -cp .;junit-4.XX.jar;hamcrest-core-1.3.jar **org.junit.runner.JUnitCore** *CalculatorTest*